# ClusterMap in R on a forked cluster is much slower than mapply. What else can I try?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mapply

I am quite new to parallel programming, and have picked up bits about R from various (sometimes contradictory) sources. 
I inherited some code and have tried to parallelise it, I think that data parallelisation is appropriate.

The task requires some computations over a number of individuals (phase 1), then the computed quantities are used to calculate some feature of the population (phase 2). We do this for a loop over some prescribed number of iterates. I have a suspicion (piecing together bits that I have read) that the computations from phase 1 cause a change to the object storing the results that is making the computation suffer from some wait time caused by (undesirable) copying of objects.
The result is program execution employing clusterMap having much greater system time than a non-parallelised version of the code using mapply.

The calculations require many levels of function calls. I have tried to give a sense of the code structure in a smallish working example below.

```
 require(parallel)

## define the two phases of the computation 
phase1.top.level<- function(x,y){second.level(x,y)}

## Functions call other functions.  
phase1.second.level<- function(x,y){   third.level(x,y) }

phase1.third.level<- function(x,y){ result<- x^2-2*y*x; result }

 ## define the function that performs the second phase of the computation     
second.phase<-function(input,x,y) {input+x+y}

## Assemble these functions into an algorithm
multi.phase.comp<- function(input,x,y){

    input<-phase1.top.level(x,y)
        output<-second.phase(input,x,y)
}


### Call the function with inputs
 x<-seq(1:100)
y<-seq(1:100)
input<-rep(1,100)

## Time the function executed for the vector inputs using clusterMap from the parallel package
system.time({ 
no_cores<-5 
    c1<- makeCluster(no_cores,type="FORK")
out<- clusterMap(cl=c1, multi.phase.comp, input, x, y)
stopCluster(c1) 
})
### One execution of this (on an old laptop) gave
###  user  system elapsed 
###  0.055   0.163   0.973 

 ## Regrettably, the effort to parallelise wasn't justified as mapply is    faster: 
system.time({ 
out2<-  mapply( multi.phase.comp, input, x, y)
})
#### This shows much less system and elapsed time 
#### user  system elapsed 
#### 0.009   0.002   0.030
```

Any suggestions on how I might speed up my code? Would I be better off with socket clusters for this type of application?

Comment: Problems with almost no computation time aren't worth executing in parallel since the computation time is much less that the overhead of sending tasks to and receiving results from the workers. If the tasks in your real problem take even 0.1 seconds to execute, the parallel version should beat mapply. But there's not much point in trying to improve the performance of this toy problem, since you'll never be able to beat 0.03 seconds.

Comment: @SteveWeston the actual code is much more involved, and too long and convoluted to serve as an illustration. Here's a realisation of the actual run times:
Opening the cluster inside one of the lower levels of the function gives
user  system elapsed 
 12.219   1.390  29.283
 so you can see elapsed time is much larger than processing time (not good)

But if I use the cluster in two places, I get 
user  system elapsed 
 11.029   1.763  71.022

Using just mapply gives an elapsed time of 5-7 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you use `mcmapply(multi.phase.comp, input, x, y, mc.cores=no_cores)` (without any makeCluster, stopCluster)?

Comment: @SteveWeston ,  10 runs of the makeCluster block give elapsed times between 0.492 sec and 0.698 sec, and elapsed time is always substantially more than the sum of user and system times. 
10 runs of a block using mcmapply as you suggest give elapsed times between 0.126 sec and 0.219 sec, and this is often less than the total of user and system times. 
It seems you're on to something here, thanks! As I used makeCluster and stopCluster only once (starting and stopping a cluster  after each function call caused processes to stall) I didn't expect there to be much difference caused by mcmapply.

Comment: @SteveWeston, Using my old laptop at home to run my *actual* code (so timings are not comparable to those shown in my last comment above) which only uses mapply has: user  system elapsed 12.367   0.352  16.773. 
Replacing one instance of mapply with mcmapply gives: 
user  system elapsed 28.964  86.500 118.165. 
It seems mcmapply alone can't help me.

Comment: I'd check to see if you have enough memory to support the workers that you're starting.

Comment: @SteveWeston I just ran the code on a multi-core machine with one mapply replaced by mcmapply as you suggested:

Comment: Results:
 user  system elapsed 
 21.358  37.604  22.440 
which has elapsed time about 3x to 4x slower than the original code.
Using top to monitor the workers shows they have %CPU taking values from 1 to 4  (most of the time processes are shown as Zombie) and %MEM shows 0.0 . I interpret this as meaning that lack of memory is not an issue. Maybe the tasks I'm trying to parallelise aren't amenable to this treatment. Or, is it worth playing around with a socket cluster?

Answer (score 3):

The parallel package doesn't work well for this type of fine-grained parallel computing, largely because it uses processes rather than threads as the workers. However, if you have a great many small tasks (such as a million rather than a hundred), you can use chunking techniques to get better performance.

Here's an example that uses mclapply:

```
# return list of arguments to seq function
slices <- function(n, chunks) {
  if (n <= 0) return(list())
  chunks <- min(chunks, n)
  m <- n %/% chunks
  length.out <- rep(m, chunks)
  r <- n - m * chunks
  length.out[seq_len(r)] <- length.out[seq_len(r)] + 1
  from <- cumsum(c(1, length.out[-chunks]))
  mapply(c, from, length.out, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
}

# compute result for a segment of the input vectors
wraptask <- function(il) {
  i <- seq(il[1], length.out=il[2])
  mapply(multi.phase.comp, input[i], x[i], y[i])
}

system.time({ 
  out3 <- do.call('c',
                  mclapply(slices(length(x), no_cores),
                           wraptask, mc.cores=no_cores))
})
```

When I ran this on your example, but using input vectors with a million elements, mapply took 5.8 seconds, and the optimized mclapply took 2.1 seconds. That's impressive in a way, but many may think it's a lot of work to do to save 3 seconds of compute time.

Comment: ah Uwe’s Maxim: "Computers are cheap and thinking hurts". I'm still impressed by the gain and might see if I can apply this thinking to the original problem and code. Thanks!